# Why does glob() returns FALSE when the directory is empty?

Tags: php, arrays, glob

I have an empty folder called `my_folder`:

```
$mas = glob("my_folder/*");
var_dump($mas);
```

If in `my_folder` I have files, the result is an array, but if `my_folder` is empty, the result is `false`.

Why is the result `false` and not an empty array()?

Comment: because there was an error

Comment: `false` indicates an error. Look into your server's error log file.

Comment: If in `my_folder` I have files, result is `array`, but if `my_folder` is empty, result is `false`...

Comment: "On some systems it is impossible to distinguish between empty match and an error." -- Could be to do with this but I don't know which systems it affects.

Comment: I originally voted to close but your last comment is helpful in understanding the problem, so I added it to your post and gave you an upvote even though this is in the manual: "*On some systems it is impossible to distinguish between empty match and an error.*"... sure, but what causes it? It must be something specific, right? I'd be interested in knowing.

Comment: So, how may I can understood what is this specific reason? server OS is "Linux", according to `php_uname()`. ( Incidentally, my hosting provider is  www.servage.net )

Comment: I can confirm that on some systems  it just returns FALSE if it finds no match. A solution can be sth like `glob(..) ?: array()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Most likely you don't have permissions on `my_folder`.
- Also it could be because (from PHP manual):

> On some systems it is impossible to distinguish between empty match and an error.

If the latter is your case i suggest you to fall back to "[classic](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)" way to do that:

```
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$entry\n";
}
```

Using:

```
opendir(), readdir(), closedir()
```

Comment: Thanks, as I see, in this case, "classic" way is really classic =)

Comment: How would I find out **why** `opendir` or `readdir` are failing? For some reason, this does not work on the server; it works on my PC. It acts like a permissions issue with the Apache account running on the server, but it is explicitly given permissions to the folder I am trying to read.

Answer (score 1):

The [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/glob) says `glob` returns `FALSE` when there is an error.  You are not getting an empty array because there is an error.

Here are some common errors with `glob`:

- you don't have permissions on the file/folder (well, `www-data` doesn't have permission, that is)
- you mistyped something
- you are trying to work on remote files (which is not supported)
- you are using an old system that doesn't have it (eg. really old S OS)

Answer (score 0):

Return Values:
Returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty array if no file matched or **FALSE on error**.

Note:
**On some systems it is impossible to distinguish between empty match and an error.**

Check both of these points are not relevant to you and your specific platform.

Answer (score 0):

From the [PHP glob manual page](http://php.net/glob) under the **Return Values** section:

> Returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty array if no file matched or FALSE on error.